# picker view cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uipickerview

i am using cocos2d and require a pickerview for one of the scenes within my game. However ccnode does not support the ui kit pickerview. Does anyone know of a reasonable way i can incorporate a pickerview into my game or perhaps know of an alternative with similar behaviour to the pickerview?

Comment: try it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594311/is-it-possible-to-use-uipickerview-in-cocos2d

Comment: You should look at CCPickerView.

Comment: i tried all night looking for it, i can't download it anywhere :(

Comment: that does not look like what i need, i need the data picked to return to my layer, the example you have shown simply creates a picker outside of the cc layer

Comment: ok i have made progress and now have a pickerview with one component containing an image, however the second component only requires integers, since - (UIView *)pickerView: returns only UIViews this is not possible, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use picker view in your scene.. Instead of adding view on self.view, add it on `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:pickerView];`
Rest all the delegate methods remain same...
Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: well i need to add it to the ccnode scene, unless i am mistaken i don't think simply doing the above would work

Comment: think i am making some progress - will keep you informed :)

Comment: You can subclass CCNode as e.g. UIKitNode and keep a reference to the UIView in there.  Then when you add or remove an instance of UIKitNode to your scene make it also add or remove the UIView.

Comment: This works fine... You don't need to add it to scene..I implemented UIImagePicker using this way.. :) Rest I don't know what exactly u want...

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted my version of CCPickerView for Cocos2d at https://github.com/fidgetware/CCPickerView.  It is a drop replacement for UIPickerView with a few extras like the ability to spin.